# Replacing the notification bar and panel in android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am trying to write my own full UI replacement (launcher/appdrawer/notifications) for android (4.0.4 primarily) however I have been having trouble finding a starting point to create a notification bar and panel. I know these feats are possible, as there are already some apps that do it. But I can't find any starter code.

Comment: I believe notification replacements use the Accessibility hooks.